# JAXB generate XML with prefix and no xmlns

Tags: namespaces, jaxb, xml-namespaces, spring-ws, prefix

I am using SpringWS and JAXB annotated classes to generate XML as a payload for a webservice client. I have created package-info.java to generate the prefix:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(xmlns =
 { 
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "pay", 
     namespaceURI =     "http://www.paymentexpress.com"),
    @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix = "xsd", 
     namespaceURI = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema") 
 }, 
 namespace = "http://www.paymentexpress.com", 
 elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED, 
 attributeFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNQUALIFIED)

package com.mycompany;
```

And this generates:

```
<pay:GetTransactionId 
        xmlns:pay="http://www.paymentexpress.com" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <pay:tranDetail>
      ...
```

The webservice client tests fail. The issue is that sending this XML with soapUI I get the same error as in tests, and when I delete the xmlns:pay declaration, it works in soapUI.

Is there any way to generate the prefix and not include the xmlns declaration in the generated XML with JAXB?